# Java sql ResultSet has no data

Tags: java, sql-server, odbc, resultset

I want to extract a only one data from my sql database in java. I tried to used the resultSet but when i want to exctract the first row into an int Variables, it said that the resultSet have no content.

Here is my code

```
try {

            statement = connexion.createStatement();
            statementArtist = connexion.createStatement();
            String artist = "Mac Miller";
            ResultSet resultat = statement.executeQuery("USE albums SELECT Album.numero_artist FROM Album INNER JOIN Artist ON Album.num_artist = Artiste.num_artist where name like '"+artist+"'");    
            int result = resultat.getInt(1); // Here is the problem
            String query = "USE albums INSERT INTO dbo.Album(Album.num_artist, title, price, genre, date, home, image) VALUES("
                    + result
                    + ", '"
                    + title
                    + "', "
                    + price
                    + ", '"
                    + genre
                    + "', '"
                    + date
                    + "', '"
                    + home
                    + "', '"
                    + image
                    + "')";
            statement.executeUpdate(query);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `next()` method on the result set to "move" the iterator:

```
...
ResultSet resultat = statement.executeQuery("USE albums SELECT Album.numero_artist FROM Album INNER JOIN Artist ON Album.num_artist = Artiste.num_artist where name like '"+artist+"'");    
resultat.next();           
int result = resultat.getInt(1); // Here is the problem
...
```

And if the security and better performance is important for your application, you should also consider using prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use next(), also should test the result i.e

```
ResultSet resultat = statement.executeQuery("USE albums SELECT Album.numero_artist FROM Album INNER JOIN Artist ON Album.num_artist = Artiste.num_artist where name like '"+artist+"'");    
if (resultat.next()) {
    int result = resultat.getInt(1); // Here is the problem
```

also the like **'"+artist+"'"** is prone to errors, e.g. if artist contains a quote "'"
you would get an Sql error with most DB's. Suppest using Sql parameters